# GIT describe output regex to get commit data

Tags: regex, git

My `git describe --long` outputs the following:

```
version-2.7.0-0-g10064b7
      ^       ^   ^
      |       |   |
      |       |   |
      |       |   |--> git commit hash
      |       |------> commit number since last tag
      |--------------> tag
```

Now, I want to use regex to get the `commit number since last tag` and `git commit hash` for my `C#` program.

How can this be achieved using regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can test your regex easily at http://regexpal.com/
To capture consecutive numbers use a character group [0-9], which is short for [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9].
Dots need to be escaped with a backslash: \.
The rest should be trivial.